# How do I do The Hole and the Ocean on iOS with no keyboard?

Tags: ios, candy-box-2

I cannot get the sponge, shell powder, or anything from the Hole as I am on iOS and I have no keyboard. Is there any way around this or am I stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *really* desperate, you could get a real Bluetooth keyboard and connect it. Otherwise, you're stuck.

Answer (score -2):

Use the teleportation spell to get close to the ocean floor, and then use the time ring to slow down.  Use your projectiles to hit and destroy the shell pile thing.